C++ free() invalid pointer in a pool implementation
I'm reading and learning Stroustrup's "programming principles and practice using c++" book. And in chapter 25 about embedding system programming, to void memory fragmentation, the book introduce two data structure: pool and stack.
So I tried to write a Pool:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Item {
    T value;
    Item* next;
};

template<typename T, unsigned long N>
class Pool {
    public:
    using size_type = unsigned long;
    
    Pool() : sz{N} {
        auto unit = sizeof(Item<T>) + sizeof(Item<T>) % alignof(Item<T>);
        avail = static_cast<Item<T>*>(malloc(unit * N));
        for (size_type i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            auto p = avail + i;
            auto n = i == N - 1 ? nullptr : avail + (i + 1);
            p->next = n;
        }
    }

    Item<T>* get() {
        if (sz == 0) throw std::runtime_error("no available space!");
        auto next = avail->next;
        auto p = new (avail) Item<T>;
        avail = next;
        p->next = nullptr;
        --sz;
        return p;
    }
    void free(Item<T>* p) {
        if (p == nullptr) return;
        delete p;
        p->next = avail;
        avail = p;
        ++sz;
    }

    size_type available() const { return sz; }

    Item<T>* avail;
    size_type sz;
};


// 500 byte object
struct Five {
    char chunk[500];

    ~Five() { std::cout << "File destructor called" << '\n'; }
};


int main() {
    try {
        constexpr int test_size = 2;
        Pool<Five, test_size> fh_pool;
        std::cout << "Pool allocation (reverse deallocate):\n";
        std::vector<Item<Five>*> vpf1 (2);

        for (auto i = 0; i < test_size; ++i)
            vpf1[i] = fh_pool.get();

        for (auto i = test_size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            std::cout << vpf1[i] << '\n';
            fh_pool.free(vpf1[i]);
        }

        return 0;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    catch(...) {
        std::cerr << "Unknown exception\n";
        return 2;
    }
}

But it doesn't work:
Program returned: 139
Program stderr
free(): invalid pointer
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

Anyone can help me about the error?
Also, I think the implementation is a little bit weird because of the tricky alignof.
I use alignof because the memory alignment thing.
Tell me if there is anthoer better method.
Update:
I try to explain the background or purpose of the code sample:
In some situation, we don't want to use free store, e.g. embedding systems programming. The issue of free store is, when we use new and delete together, it will cause holes in memory:

If there are too many holes, it will dramatically increase the time to execute new as it has to search through lots of objects and fragments for a suitably sized chunk of memory.
So, we mustn’t cause fragmentation. What do we do then? The first simple observation is that new cannot by itself cause fragmentation; it needs delete to create the holes. So we start by banning delete. That implies that once an object is allocated, it will stay part of the program forever.
In the absence of delete, is new predictable; that is, do all new operations take the same amount of time? Yes, in all common implementations, but it is not actually guaranteed by the standard. Usually, an embedded system has a startup sequence of code that establishes the system as “ready to run” after initial power-up or restart. During that period, we can allocate memory any way we like up to an allowed maximum. We could decide to use new during startup. Alternatively (or additionally) we could set aside global (static) memory for future use.
There are two data structures that are particularly useful for predictable memory allocation:
Pools: A pool is a collection of objects of the same size. We can allocate and deallocate objects as long as we don’t allocate more objects than the pool can hold. There can be no fragmentation because all objects are of the same size.
Stacks: ...
Update2:
I rewrote a new code example for those who want to refer:
https://godbolt.org/z/e77ffchGj

delete p; is incorrect. You allocated an item using placement new, so you should not call delete on it. Instead, just invoke its destructor. Also note that you should not access or modify members of p after destructing it, which currently you are doing.

@paddy OK, I see. Now I know delete p shouldn't be called. So after replace delete p; with p->~Item<T>();, it seems work! But I still need to maintain the chain, that is, I still need to write p->next = avail; like I do in Pool() constructor. But you say "I shouldn't access or modify members of p after destructing it.", so what should I do then.

The whole thing is a bit of a mess to be honest. It's unclear what responsibility the list has. You build a whole list of uninitialized T objects at the beginning, but then you do list operations when allocating and freeing. None of this is helped by the fact that there's no comments in your code explaining responsibilities or logic. So, is the list structure supposed to be static? Or is it supposed to represent live objects? If the latter, then you should realize that if you free objects in the wrong order, everything will get messed up. Note that once you modify avail, you leak memory.

Regarding "so what should I do then" -- to begin with, think about whether Item is useful at all outside of Pool. I think it's not. It's an internal class used to manage the pool's values. Your pool should be handing out T* values, and accepting those in the free method. You happen to know these will always have the same address as the Item which contains them. Store allocated items in a separate list (i.e. keep another pointer). Don't ever lose the pointer to your main buffer. Consider using doubly-linked lists so that deletion doesn't require a search.

@paddy I just updated some background in the question.

@paddy Wow, does Item and T have same addresses? Because value is the first member? That's cool. Is there guarantee in C++ standard?
I agree with that I should handing out T* values and accepting those in free. But I don't know how to do because if I keep allocated items in a separate list, when I accept a T* in free(), how can I find the next in O(1) time, in this situation, I need to search throught the list.

Yes, except in special cases (none of which apply here), this is guaranteed. As I mentioned, you need a double-linked list if you want O(1) deletion from a list. You could get away with a single-linked list but it's complicated and I don't think you should do it. Basically it involves repurposing an unused bit of the next pointer to mark the item as dirty, then doing partial updates of your active-list. Here is your code with some of the changes I recommended. It searches the free-list on deletion. Using a double-linked list is an exercise for you.

About member addresses see : class.mem (#29) from the C++ standard

Not sure what are you all talking about regarding double linked lists. Single linked list of free items like used here (or rather stack, since we only need the first element), would be quite enough. There is no need to track live items. Just get an item from top of the stack when allocating, and put freed element back on the stack.

@AndreyTurkin That's fine if allocation and deallocation happens in stack order, but the interface shown makes absolutely no such guarantees. It simply provides a function to get a new object and a function to release a specified object. These can be called in any order. Some pool schemes enforce stack ordering, and some pools do not provide any way to free individual objects (i.e. arena allocation). The implementation in this question is neither. I will add that in a stack pool allocator, a linked list of free items is not required at all.

@paddy there is no need for a particular ordering though. If there would be, there wouldn't be any need for a list at all. I didn't mean stack poll allocator, I'm saying a stack of free slots is enough for a generall pool allocator. In get pop top of stack as an allocation slot, in free - put it on top of stack. That's all, nothing more needed.

Oh right, I see what you're talking about. I was stuck in the mindset of ensuring that the pool correctly tracks allocations, which would be necessary if one is lazy and also using non-POD types and expecting the pool to safely clean up. But as you say, it's fine to not do that and expect the caller to manage object lifetime safely.

@paddy But without tracking allocations, we cannot destruct those values like you write in ~Pool() of your example. Did you mean that if the user only passes POD types, it's ok to not calling item->value.~T()?

@a1mersnow no, one just can require users to ensure pool outlives any allocations made from it. That way by the time ~Pool() frees the memory any objects inside that memory must be already destroyed by whoever allocated them from the pool. If you think about it, this sort of requirement is not limiting at all - otherwise we could easily crash the program since the memory would be freed while someone might still be using it. Memory pool, generally speaking, does not absolve its users from memory management. Specialized autocleaning pools can be done, but this one is not it.

@AndreyTurkin, do you mean it's the user's responsibility to do the destruction? i.e. The pool only needs to free the space it allocated previously.
auto a = pool.get(); // some usage of a... a->~X();

Well yeah. Just like when doing normal ::new ... Generally pool allocators are a performance enhancers, they don't change allocation semantics.

@a1mersnow I misread your comment a bit. I mean user should do auto* a = pool.get(); ... use a; ...; pool.free(a);. User should pair their gets with their frees, and also ensure everything is freed before destroying pool itself. Pool should do T->~T(); in its free, just like it did new()() in its get(). Pool creates objects, pool destroys objects. Pool manages memory. Users just need to make sure they return what they took from the pool, eventually.

Yes, that's what I mean. If it's completely acceptable that destroying the pool without calling free on all objects currently allocated by the pool results in undefined behavior and/or leaks, then this is fine. And it would be pretty expected for this to be the case. Failing to do so is slightly more severe than a normal leak where the object just sits around in a valid memory block, as in this case the object would have the rug pulled out from under it and "occupy" memory that has been released. That could be very bad for more complex types (e.g. a worker thread + associated data).

This is a bit of a hot mess.

unit size calculations are wrong for overaligned types; e.g. imagine T is 8 byte sized but 32-byte aligned. You'd get unit==16 but it should be 32.
malloced data are not properly aligned for overaligned types (see example above)
Pool uses Item::next of non-created or already-destroyed objects. I'm pretty sure that is a big UB no-no
Pool destructor leaks memory (no pair for that malloc)
Pool should probably be using T* in its API, not Item<T>*, that's an implementation detail and not to be exposed to its users
Actual error that crashes: Pool::free() shouldn't delete memory!

    void free(Item<T>* p) {
        delete p;   // <<!?
    }

Allocating new must be paired with delete, but placement new must be paired with explicit destructor call; there is no memory block to delete! Whole idea of a pool is to reclaim memory internally for later use.
And that error you really should've figured out on your own. It's not like it was some obscure heap corruption; simple plain gdb backtrace would've pointed you to that line.

Why T is 8 byte sized but align can be 32-byte? Even it is, unit will be 16 (which is 8 + 8 % 32). However, if it can be that case(align is larger than size), I indeed did wrong calculation.

Sure can be; like a said, over-aligned types are a thing. struct alignas(32) T { void* p; };. There are valid reasons to do so, e.g. to avoid false sharing in multithreaded applications.

Let's talk about 3. You say it's a big UB to use Item::next of non-crewated objects. But without that, how to construct the list of free objects?

One way would be not to use Item struct but do something more union-like (but not union itself). Notice T and next lifetimes are disjoint, so they can share same memory, provided it is sufficiently large and aligned for the pointer. Safe way would be to do placement new "next" pointer into the memory before assigning to it (and then std::launder ing it before usage). Or std::start_lifetime_as in C++23. Or maybe just cast it to pointer and use it like C allows?! Really not sure on that last one; implicit lifetime types are a thing but I'm fuzzy on that topic.

I don't understand your advice... Could you show me by some code?
Here is an example modified from previous code:
https://godbolt.org/z/WheMqrYr5

"T and next lifetimes are disjoint..." It sounds just like a union but you said don't use union...

That's right, because lifetime of union members is a mess, and I think it is incompatible with what you need it to do. But see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Providing_storage for an example of a storage what provides union-like guarantees on both size and alignment of its "members", as well as placement new usage to explicitely start its members' lifetime.
